# How to programmatically redirect to Azure AD sign-in and sign-out pages in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

My ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app is using Azure AD to authenticate users. In startup.cs I added Azure AD:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
  options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
  options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
});
```

Authorization is done by a policy check:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", policy => {
      policy.RequireClaim("groups", adminGroupId);
  });
});
```

In appsettings.json I have all the required configuration:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "662f1be2-...",
    "ClientId": "30eb6c27-...",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}
```

If I try to access a controller decorated with `[Authorize(Policy = "AdministratorOnly")]` it will redirect to Azure AD and handle the login process and eventually redirect back to my app.

Questions:

- Is there a prescribed to kick off the login process (preferably in a popup window)? Where do I get the URL from to redirect to?
- How can I provide a button to let users logout again? If I redirect to "/signout-oidc" I'm getting signed out but I end up on a blank page.

Comment: Call `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync()` and `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` respectively to log in or log out. It will automatically terminate the request with the correct redirect result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation explains it all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp). It is backed by a [solid source code repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC).

In general, the AzureAD middleware is taking care about redirection to Azure AD when the user is not authenticated. This is checked every time user ends up on action decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute.

As for Logout - if you use the oidc-logout, check out [the sample and explanations here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-6-SignOut).

Comment: That helped. With the vast amount of documentation and the use of different endpoints, product names and libraries it isn't always easy to find exactly the right thing. So thanks for pointing me to the relevant parts.

Comment: Hi @Krumelur : I have also same question. How you have achieved  a button to let users logout again.

Comment: By calling these HttpContext.ChallengeAsync() and HttpContext.SignOutAsync()  manually on button clicks ?